# Working with the CurrentRow in a DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Is there way to set `CurrentRow` in a `DataGridView` to `null` when a `Form` is first loaded? I want to do this so the `CurrentChanged` event on my `BindingSource` does not fire.

To clarify, when the `Form` is initially loaded, I don't want any rows to be selected in my `DataGridView`. And I want `BindingSource.CurrentChanged` to fire only when the user selects a row.

Answer (score 0):

CurrentRow is readonly. 
I think you should set the CurrentCell to null.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set `e.Cancel = true;` in the event to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the row selection using `this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();` method. I don't know whether it is work with you scenario or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
               foreach(DataGridViewCell Cell datagridview1.SelectedCells)
              {
                      Cell.Seleted=false;
              }
```

i hope this will solve your problem.